# Bootstrap File Input -Kartik - fails wihout error message when used with require.js , AngularJS

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set up this plugin with my project
http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input  the demo is here, http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo
It is quite easy to set up, 
however my project uses AngularJS, requirejs to load all dependencies 
and angular-ui router so therefore I add the require css file to my html page and then I point to the .js file from the require.js config file, when I do this, the plugin simple fails without any error message. Does someone have any clue what the problem is or is it that the plugin does not work with require.js

here is my require config file

```
require.config({
baseUrl: "/Client/"
, paths: {
    "jquery": "libs/jquery-1.10.2.min"
    , 'async': 'plugins/requirejs-plugins/async'
          , "angular": "libs/angularjs1.3/angular"
      , "bootstrapFileInput": "plugins/bootstrapfileinput/js/fileinput"
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

***Require.js*** isolates your javascript from other scripts to avoid conflicts. You need to specify which dependencies ***fileinput*** requires in the configuration ***shim***.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'bootstrap': 'path/to/bootstrap.min',
        'fileinput': 'path/to/fileinput',
        'jquery': 'path/to/jquery.min'
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap" : {
            "deps" :['jquery']
        },
        "fileinput" : {
            "deps" :['jquery','bootstrap']
        }
    }
});
require(['bootstrap','fileinput'],function(){});
```

The second ***require*** invocation will trigger the asynchronous load. 
***Fileinput*** will scan the dom and alter any inputs it finds once it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem too.
maybe the version of require.js is  incompatible with your bootstrap-input component.you can try again with a lower version of require.js such as 1.0.8

Comment: This seems to be more a comment than an answer. Could you provide some documentation to substantiate this?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem!
When I use this plugin simply without requirejs .everything is OK.
But when I use this with requirejs, it looks like normal, the initialize code seems to work normally. Which has no error in the console.but when I upload a file via it.
This plugin does not post the file data to my server using the URL which I configured in the initial parameter, it just post the data to current page URL.

The specified JavaScript library as follow:

RequireJS 2.1.15
jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.2
Bootstrap-fileinput v4.3.5

The file loading detail is:

Loading CSS file with traditional method
the jQuery, bootstrp and fileinput JavaScript loaded by the requirejs.

**I find it works OK with low versions requirejs (1.0.8)
if your project can use low version requirejs. You can try this solution**